# расположение JPanel на нужном месте

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Не могу заставить располагаться кнопку на нужном месте, делаю **Layout** командой `add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`и `add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);` не получается.
Смысл в том, что я хочу одной кнопкой переключать видимость определенной JPanel, и вроде бы это получается, но вот панели не находятся в нужном месте, хотя их расположение я задаю, помогите пожалуйста найти ошибку

```
 enum ViewState {
    START_STATE, NEXT_STATE; }

class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
    public CenterPanel() {
        JPanel  centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.cyan);

        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JButton button = new JButton("ONE");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyWindows.changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);
            }
        });
        centerPanel.add(button);
        this.add(centerPanel);
    } }

class ButtonPanel extends JPanel {
    public ButtonPanel() {
        JPanel  buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(Color.blue);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        JButton button = new JButton("TWO");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                MyWindows.changeState(ViewState.NEXT_STATE);
            }
        });
        buttonPanel.add(button);
        this.add(buttonPanel);
    } }

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyWindows MW = new MyWindows();

    } }

class MyWindows extends JFrame {
    private static ViewState viewState;
    private static JFrame frame;
    private static JPanel mpanel;
    private static JPanel panelUp;
    private static JPanel panelDown;

    protected MyWindows(){
        frame = new JFrame();
        mpanel = new JPanel();
        panelUp = new CenterPanel();
        panelDown = new ButtonPanel();

        changeState(ViewState.START_STATE);

        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.add(mpanel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void changeState(ViewState state) {
        viewState = state;
        System.out.println("change state: " + viewState);

        switch (state) {
            case START_STATE:
                mpanel.removeAll();
                mpanel.add(panelDown);

                mpanel.revalidate();
                mpanel.repaint();
                break;
            case NEXT_STATE:
                mpanel.removeAll();
                mpanel.add(panelUp);

                mpanel.revalidate();
                mpanel.repaint();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("UNKNOWN STATE!");
                break;
        }
    } }
```

Comment: и дайте пожалуйста советы как я могу улучшить свой код

Comment: может объясните что вы имеете ввиду под переклчением видимости

Comment: @RomanC у меня есть две панели `ButtonPanel` и `CenterPanel`, я нажимаю **ONE**, и вижу первую панель, нажимаю **TWO**, и вижу другую панель

Comment: то есть с видимостью проблем нет?

Comment: я не уверен что дело только в этом, но вы забыли указать layout для самих панелей CenterPanel ButtonPanel

Answer (score 0):

я упустил один момент, в конструкторе я указывал нужный компоновщик, но упустил тот момент, что его надо так же установить в классе `MyWindows`, что бы все расставить на свои места, например класс панели `CenterPanel` у меня выглядит так:

```
class CenterPanel extends JPanel {
    public CenterPanel() {
        JPanel  centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    }
}
```

а строки кода, где я вызываю его в `MyWindows` так:

```
class MyWindows extends JFrame {
private static JPanel panelUp;
protected MyWindows(){
panelUp = new CenterPanel();

frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
 frame.add(panelUp, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panelUp.setLayout(new GridLayout());
frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```